# Use a Regex to convert Smarty syntax to PHP syntax

Tags: php, regex, templates, preg-replace, smarty

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP templating using custom code replacing using regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5299498/php-templating-using-custom-code-replacing-using-regex)

Hi,

I would like to convert

```
<a href="{$game.url}">{$game.info.cleanname}</a>
```

to

```
<a href="$game['url']">$game['info']['cleanname']</a>
```

using preg_replace

Comment: What is the relation between the question and the title?

Comment: Do you mean `<?php echo $game['info']['cleanname']; ?>`

Comment: @mike B yes and it does relate to the question. damn you guys are quick to downvote.

Comment: @user658911 I didn't downvote nor vote to close.

Answer (score 1):

There was a question asking for exactly the same yesterday:
[PHP templating using custom code replacing using regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5299498/php-templating-using-custom-code-replacing-using-regex)

Simply add a second preg_replace version (or more) to match the other cases:

```
preg_replace('/\{\$(\w+)\.(\w+)\}/', '\\$$1[\'$2\']', $src);
```

If you need more help with that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89718/is-there-anything-like-regexbuddy-in-the-open-source-world

Comment: would it replace all the occurences of the code above

Comment: and does it work for nested arrays